# Не открываются страницы сайта wordpress после переноса

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, apache, wordpress

Перенес сайт с тестового хостинга на денвер на локальной машине вместе с БД, делал все как всегда и вроде бы сайт работает, но не все так просто. Главная страница открывается, а вот все остальные не хотят. Выдает вот такую ошибку

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, admin@example.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
>
> Apache/2.2.22 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.3.13 Server at journal Port 80

Сколько не гуглил, не могу понять, в чем именно проблема. Не могли бы вы объяснить и помочь в решении вопроса.

Comment: "More information about this error may be available in the server error log." — найдите лог ошибок сервера и добавьте его к этому вопросу. Тогда можно будет что-то ответить (а может, и сами поймете).

Answer (score 3):

Вот как получилось решить проблему. немного еще погуглил и понял, что может глючить 1 плагин, который переводит ссылку. Нашел папку "plugins" и переименовал ее, тем самым отключив их. Затем зашел в админку ВП и поменял в настройках постоянные ссылки. Папку плагин переименовал обратно в plugins и все заработало.